# Is there DropShadow effect on ImageBrush

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Is there `DropShadow` effect on `ImageBrush` for Windows Phone 8.1 XAML

I need shadow effect on `ImageBrush` only in Xaml or in vb.net code

Answer (score 1):

Dop Shadow is not avialable for Image brush . You can use Expression Blend to see if there is any workaround

Comment: It's not in EB either. You have to make your custom effect or a style.

Comment: he would use EB for that I suppose

Comment: Hi, actually  I need image inside cricle, so I am using ImageBrush inside Ellipse, then I am getting the design, next i need is a shadow of it

Comment: Sure EB is for that. I mean that for WPF the is a built in shadow effect, but it's unavailable for WP and he has to make his own.